# MongoDB, Java: accessing cursor opens connection that cannot be closed

Tags: java, mongodb, connection

I have problem to close a connection that is always created after accessing the MongoDB cursor.

I am gathering the information about the connections from the console of the running mongod instance. I am not using any mongodb replication nor sharding yet.

For example a sample code causing an opened connection (assume 'myQuery' is just some query, coll is mapped using setInternalClass to the class MyObject):

```
  DBCursor find = coll.find(myQuery);
  List<MyObject> myObjects = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
  while(find.hasNext()) { // this line opens the connection
        MyObject next = (MyObject) find.next();
        myObjects.add(next);
  }
  find.close(); // this line will not close the connection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling close on your find object, which is a DBCursor. As mentioned in the [API Documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DBCursor.html) this will close only the cursor, not the underlying connection. To close the connections you should call close on the Mongo/MongoClient object, which either inherits or has a close function that will [as per the API](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/Mongo.html) close all connections to the MongoDB server instance.

Comment: Hi daveh, thank you. However, it is also good practise to have one mongo client instance for the whole running application, therefore calling close on the client in an enterprise application is not a good idea, is it?

Comment: The driver has a connection pool, which can be configured via MongoOptions to have a number of established idle connections open at all times to facilitate faster querying. You are correct in saying that you should not need to close this pool until your application is terminating.

Comment: So in other words, I can ignore the opened connections, because MongoDB will take care of it and will close some of them when needed?

Comment: Thats the general principal. You should check the Java driver concurrency page, it has much of the deail-> http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/java-concurrency/

Comment: Sorry, investigating the same issue because of the OutOfMemory. Is it therefore ok to have [conn3500] in the log file? I doubt it is. (the number raises and none is closed)